# Submit form to iframe and load that iframe in another html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an Form submitting to an iframe in Page1.html.
I want this iframe to show up in a new IE tab so I would like to show this up in say Page2.html. Is there a correct way to do this and how should Page2.html look like? So far it is iframe is still coming up in Page1.

Page1.html

```
<html>
<head> 
   <script>
    function callMe()
    { 
    document.getElementById('TheForm').submit();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:callMe()">
   <iframe id="myIframe" name="myIframe" src="Page2.html"/>
   <form id="TheForm" method="post" action="https://myUrl" target="myIframe">
    ....blah.....
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Page2.html  (How should this Page2 display the iframe in its Body??)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 What shoud go here ??
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to open a new tab, way are you not submitting the form to a new tab? Why are you targeting the iframe?

Comment: I want the new tab to have a iframe. Is my callMe() funtion wrong?

Comment: Display what iframe in its body? I really have no clue what you are trying to do. You submit a form to an iframe and that iframe will have the result in it. Not sure how you expect to open up a new tab....

Comment: so right now the iframe displays the Form's result in the same webPage. I am trying to display the content in a separate webPage instead of the original.

Comment: Well you would need to submit the form to a new window... but there is no way you can say to open it up in some random new iframe.... You would have to do something strange for that....

Comment: Or is there a way I can post the form's result to a new webPage's iframe.
 So say Page2.html will have the iframe and I would want to invoke that iframe from Page1.?